# Module not found , its been showing the given below error even after i reinstalled and checked every address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, material-ui

./src/components/showStudent/showStudent.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/data-grid' in 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Database\client\src\components\showStudent

Code below in showstudent was  copied directly from materialui website for tables

Answer (score 1):

You are using DataGrid but it's not installed in the project.

Choose your favorite package manager, install @material-ui/data-grid.

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/data-grid

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/data-grid
```

Now, you have to import the component as below. To avoid name conflicts the component is named DataGrid.

```
import { DataGrid } from "@material-ui/data-grid";
```